# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, babeljs

I am trying to run React Native Web via Expo.

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

As far as I can tell, this is due to some module export issue.

I have created a babel.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    "presets": [
      ["babel-preset-expo", {
      "web": {
        "disableImportExportTransform": true
      }
    }]
    ]
  };
};
```

Which is similar to what https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-expo suggests

However, I am still getting this error.

How do I solve this? I had React Native Web working on another computer, but temporarily had to move computers, and I am having quite a bit of trouble configuring it to work again.

If it helps, it seems to be related to a specific module I am using:

```
E:/MyProjectOfficial/Frontend/MyProjectFrontendExpo/node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/dateutils.js:145

> 145 | module.exports = {
  146 |   weekDayNames,
  147 |   sameMonth,
  148 |   sameWeek,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
 [
  'babel-preset-expo',
  {
    web: { disableImportExportTransform: false }
     },
   ],
  ],
   };
```

I had the same problem this evening and I fixed it using the same article as you. The key was to set the option to false instead of true in the `babel.config.ja`. That did it for me and I hope it can help you as well.